# Why does Analyse Data in Excel give different result from OLS Stats Model in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, statsmodels

I'm trying to predict sales with multiple linear regression with variables X1 = customers and X2 = KiloWattHour(kWh). But when I try in Excel and try in Python, the results are different.

Data in Excel:

```
Sales (Y) KWH (X1) Customer(X2)
2,72       3,13      174
2,59       3,03      175
2,81       3,28      175
2,66       3,14      117
2,80       3,29      87
2,71       3,13      74
2,93       3,33      68
2,71       3,10      104
```

Data in CSV imported to Python:

```
Sales (Y) KWH (X1) Customer(X2)
2.72       3.13      174
2.59       3.03      175
2.81       3.28      175
2.66       3.14      117
2.80       3.29      87
2.71       3.13      74
2.93       3.33      68
2.71       3.10      104
```

Code for reading the CSV file:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn import linear_model
import statsmodels.api as sm

data = pd.read_csv('/code/master_data.csv')

print(data)
```

This is code for prediction using linear regression:

```
x = data[['kwhpenjualan','totalpelanggan']]
y = data['totalpendapatan']

x_1 = sm.add_constant(x)

model = sm.OLS(y, x_1)
result = model.fit()
result.params
```

This is the result in Excel:

```
Intercept     -2,345215066
KWH (X1)      1,618236605
Customer (X2) 0,002576039
```

This is the result in Python:

```
Intercept         127.619065
KWH               -45.949302
Customer.         50.262137
dtype: float64
```

Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: if it is multiple linear regression. You need to specify the independent variable in a regression function rather than passing a data frame. See the documentation: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html

Comment: I see the code `x_1 = sm.add_constant(x)`, it should not be there. Did you run my code? Or provide the dataset, so that we can reproduce the error.

Comment: Probably you used different data for Excel and Python. I tested your example and it gives exactly the same result in Excel and Python (`const           0.019700
KWH (X1)        0.865949
Customer(X2)   -0.000255)`